# Django queryset Datefield compare against today

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model where I have a start("inicia") and end("finaliza") date and I need to know if today is between those dates:

model:

```
class Promos(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    aplica_codigo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    descuento = models.FloatField()
    porciento = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    inicia = models.DateField()
    finaliza = models.DateField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

the "inicia" and "finaliza" are the datefields that I want to check against today

I have tried the following:

```
today = date.today()
Promos.objects.filter(codigo = codigo_forma, inicia__gte = today,finaliza__lte=today).exists()
```

printing this is what I get:

```
today = 2022-08-25

print((Promos.objects.filter(codigo = codigo_forma).values("inicia", "finaliza")))

<QuerySet [{'inicia': datetime.date(2022, 8, 23), 'finaliza': datetime.date(2022, 11, 30)}]>
```

The result of the complete queryset is empty:
<QuerySet []>

I can´t figure out what is the correct format that I need to compare today against the model date fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed up `gte` and `lte`. As it stands, your code checks that `inicia` is after today and `finaliza` is before today. You want to switch the two, like this:

```py
today = date.today()
Promos.objects.filter(codigo=codigo_forma, inicia__lte=today, finaliza__gte=today).exists()
```

Comment: daaaaang, I was so bummed that I never noticed that detail, thanks!!